# Replace multiple string containing a string with Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, data-science

This work for the string "AAA" :

```
df['B'] = df.A.str.replace(r'(^.*AAA.*$)', 'ZZZ',  regex=True)
```

How can I do if I want to replace multiple string by 'ZZZ'?

```
df['B'] = df.A.str.replace(r'(^.*AAA.*$)' or r'(^.*BBB.*$)', 'ZZZ',  regex=True)
```

I tried this but it does not work

Comment: Combine the two strings into one regex pattern using '|' instead of 'or'

Comment: df['B'] = df.A.str.replace(r'(^.*AAA.*$)'|'(^.*BBB.*$)', 'ZZZ',  regex=True) works great thanks